# Sliding Menu conflict with another viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, slidingmenu

I have a sliding menu in my project which is a TableViewController and slides from left to right as u can see in the photos.

The problem is that the sliding menu contents are visible under one of the viewcontrollers!

Note that im using Autolayout. When i turn of Autolayout the problem is solved but obviously some other problems occur and most of the objects in my views get disarranged.

- The sliding menu:

[image]

- This is it,see how its visible under one of the viewcontroller,(this is with autolayout turned on which is supposed to work fine) :

[image]

Comment: What about some code? And which sliding panel you used? Any info about that will help us to undestand the question.

Comment: Hi rohan, Im using this class its called ECSlidingmenu (https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) 
And about the code i got more than 10 different classes so there's plenty of code,let me know which one wud help and ill copy it here. thx for ur help ;)